# IBM Watson Assistant with Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: node.js, botframework, ibm-watson

I'm trying to integrate Watson Assistant with Microsoft Bot framework using NodeJS.
There are individual nodeJS apps developed for:

1. Simple Echo bot, connects with Microsoft bot framework and give response (in Bot Emulator) (https://github.com/akash-tha/EchoChatbotwithBotFramework.git)
2. Connects with Watson Assistant in web session and give response back (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple.git)

But I am unable to integrate them as I am new to nodeJS and not much familiar with it. Could you please help on this. I would be very grateful!!

EDIT: I am getting warnings while hitting the conversation, such as: `(node:25036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.status(...).json is not a function UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict` And response from the dialog is not coming in Bot emulator.

Comment: please describe what you have tried and which errors have occurred.

Comment: I am getting warnings while hitting the conversation, such as:
(node:25036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.status(...).json is not a function

 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`

And response from the dialog is not coming in Bot emulator.

Comment: You need to share code. The methods you are invoking are throwing errors, probably because of coding errors in your app, and it appears that your app is only expecting good responses. This in itself is a coding error. You need to amend your code to catch and report the errors, which will give you a good idea of the errors in your code that give rise to the errors being thrown.

Comment: @chughts Thank you for suggesting, I improvised the code and with reference to one project posted on git-hub, it is working now. If needed, please check on https://github.com/vperrinfr/BotBuilder-Watson/issues/3

Comment: https://github.com/bchanda1/IBM_Watson_Assistant_Microsoft_Teams_Integration I created another V2 API version.